# Volatile.Write freshness guarentee

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory-barriers

The documentation for [`Volatile.Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.volatile.write?view=netframework-4.7.2) says the following:

> Writes the specified object reference to the specified field. On
>   systems that require it, inserts a memory barrier that prevents the
>   processor from reordering memory operations as follows: If a read or
>   write appears before this method in the code, the processor cannot
>   move it after this method.

and

> **value** `T`
>   The object reference to write. The reference is written
>   immediately so that it is visible to all processors in the computer.

But it seems like quotes 1 and 2 are contradictory.

For the second quote to be true, I would think that the first quote would have to be changed as follows:

> If a read or
>   write appears <strike>before</strike> **after** this method in the code, the processor cannot
>   move it <strike>after</strike> **before** this method.

Does `Volatile.Write` actually mean that other threads are guaranteed to pick up the write in a timely fashion, or is the second quote misleading?

It seems to me as though all these "Volatile"/"Memory Barriers" seem to be focused on is ensuring that if writes are exposed to other threads they are exposed in the correct order, but I can't seem to find what actually would be force them to be exposed.

I understand that it may be hard/impossible to expose writes to other threads immediately, but without volatile writes/reads there are cases when the writes are exposed *never*. So it seems there must be a way to ensure that writes are exposed "eventually", but I'm unsure what that is. Is it that writes are always exposed in `.NET` but reads can be cached? And if so does `Volatile.Read` stop this caching behaviour?

(Note I have read through [Joseph Albahari's Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) which tends to suggest I need explicit memory barriers before my reads and after my writes, although it's not clear why even that should be effective as the documentation for [`Thread.MemoryBarrier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.memorybarrier?view=netframework-4.7.2) doesn't seem to explicitly say that the writes are shown to other threads).

Answer (score 4):

You are misunderstanding the concept of barriers a little bit. As you wrote

> The object reference to write. The reference is written immediately so that it is visible to all **processors** in the computer.

So the really important unit here is a processor, not thread.

So, there are processors, processor caches, store buffers and invalidation queues involved.
When a processor writes something into the memory, it looks like that or similar to that
[image]

The subject is at the store buffer level. As you can see, there are a lot of things is going on when you write something or read, and it does not happen instantly for all the processors in the system. At the beginning a read or write command is places into processor's store buffer, and those commands could be reordered, in other words, executed in different order by the processor.

While that happens, other processors don't know about changes, if the operation is write and the currently working processor doesn't know about changes other processors made.

When you place a barrier, that means that operations in the store buffer or invalidation queue should be completed before any read or write could be performed. *That is necessary to actualize CPU caches across processors*. So there is basically no mechanics to synchronize any data across threads, we are syncing data across processors.

When a thread A writes something on processor 1 and thread B reads something on the processor 1, they both starts by looking into the store buffer first, so they read actual data, whether any barriers placed or not.

It's just an overview of the mechanic involved, maybe I'm wrong in some details. You can find complete info if you read about [MESI protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol), [this PDF with explanation on invalidation queues and store buffers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi_x_2D3fngAhVkw4sKHb08D-4QFjAEegQIBxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww2.in.tum.de%2Fhp%2Ffile%3Ffid%3D1276&usg=AOvVaw3OG_NC0u_LmyFeyEqrR0gc)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with you that the description in the MSDN documentation is bit confusing. I would say that "immediately" is strong word here as well as in regards to any subject related to parallel processes. The result won't be visible immediately but documentation doesn't say that - it says that the value will be written immediately, that is as soon as all prior load/store operation results become globally visible the store operation to write a value will be immediately initiated.

As for the memory barriers, they only can give a guarantee of prior operations exposure (global visibility) because in essence the memory barriers are instructions which are encountered by a CPU make the CPU "wait" for getting all pending load/store operations globally visible while the moment of global visibility of value written by `Volatile.Write` is neither barrier nor `Volatile.Write` concern.

Now about suggestion to use the barrier in lock-free programming. Of course it makes sense because it ensures the order of global visibility which is actual for multi-core systems. When you cannot be sure that an event B always happens after event A you just can't build reliable logic supposed to be executed in multi-core environemnts.